# what is purpose of this type of css?

Tags: javascript, css

I was wondering what is purpose of this type of css and js files below is example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://example.com.pk/lib/css/fancybox.style.css?v=1.4">
```

What is css?v=1.4 and some time i found js?v=1.3 why these parameter are given ?

Answer (score 3):

it is using for JS, CSS Versioning to Update Browser Cache when Files are Changed

Answer (score 0):

They are used in order to retrieve a specific version of the given resource (e.g., a CSS file).

Answer (score 0):

This is a link that loads a css file.
The href attribute shows us the location(url in this case).

The css?v=1.4 is part of a query string and probably is part of this specific css version.

Mostly this is added in the query string to avoid cache(the browser caches css\js files) and if you change the url, it doesn't find the file in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

It's a file version indicator. Most likely it's used in the link path to control caching on the file.
With this variable, the site administrator can change the URL for the stylesheet as specified in the document head, without actually changing the file-name.
Routers, browsers, etc. that cache resources will see a new url, and make a full request for the document back to the server, returning the updated file instead of a cached version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, if the file in the link ends with .css it does not necessarily have to be direct link to the specified file. Server internally can rewrite this link to some server side script (asp,php,...) which then, based on the query parameter (v=4) decides which file to serve.

Also, google used those to decide which library of it's api to load. Which basically comes back to paragraph I already wrote before.

Further more, this can be also used to be sure that browser loads new version of the script. For example, if you always load `style.css`, browsers tend to cache those for faster loading (unless specifically told otherwise) which can later interfere with changes. You might change something in your .css file and not see it in browser, because browser served cached version instead of the live one. Thus, you add ?v=X where X is increment from last version (or something totally new) to make sure browsers do not load from cache.

It really depends on the implementation of the query parameter at the server side. It is also possible that it does nothing, and serves just as a reference in html for developer.